# is it possible to set page content type on a condition in jsp or to set different content type for a single jsp

Tags: java, xml, json, jsp

I want to display JSON & XML using a single jsp page.
at a time only one attribute will come from the java class.
My code something look like this.

```
<%
        String json = (String) request.getAttribute("userRequestedJsonById");
        if (!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {%>
            <%=json%>
        <% } else { %>
            <%
            String xml = (String) request.getAttribute("searcherRespondedXmlById");
            if(!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(xml)) {%>
                <%@page contentType="text/xml"%>
                <%=xml%>
            <%}%>
        <%}%>
```

I am having a plugin called JSONVIEW to display the json properly.which doesn't work if it finds content type xml.
Content type is set only on the condition,jsp is including this content type even condition is not satisfied.
I don't know much how jsp set content type works,is there any other way to do this or to restrict to set content type xml on a particular condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `<%@page contentType="text/xml;application/json"%>`. I haven't tried it. But, still. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the content type needs to be done *before* printing anything out, so you need to get rid of the pointless opening and closing of tags that causes whitespace to be printed.  Then you will use `response.setContentType()`:

```
<%
   String json = (String) request.getAttribute("userRequestedJsonById");
   if (!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(json)) 
   {
       response.setContentType("application/json");
       out.print(json);
   }
   else 
   {
       String xml = (String) request.getAttribute("searcherRespondedXmlById");
       if(!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(xml)) 
       {
          response.setContentType("text/xml");
          out.print(xml);
       }
   }
%>
```

Its also just cleaner if you're going to use Scriptlets to just keep your code block open and use `out.print()` rather than opening, closing, and then <%=var%>, and opening again. That's just so unreadable.